# validates_uniqueness_of can't check on unsaved data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model called `Science Subject Choice`

```
class ScienceSubjectChoice < SubjectChoice
    belongs_to :subject
    belongs_to :subject_preference
    validates_associated :subject
    validates_associated :subject_preference
        #TODO: validation
    validates :priority, :presence => true, :numericality => true, :inclusion => {:in => 1..SubjectPreference::MAX_SCIENCE_SUBJECT_CHOICE}

    validates_uniqueness_of :subject_id, :scope => :subject_preference_id
    validates_uniqueness_of :priority, :scope => :subject_preference_id
end
```

the uniqueness validator don't work on unsaved data?
How can I solve it?

Solution:
Instead of validating in itself, the parent object should do the validation:

```
def validate_science_subject_choices_uniqueness
    if science_subject_choices.map(&:priority) != science_subject_choices.map(&:priority).uniq
      errors[:base] << "Duplicated priority in science subject"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Validations do not work like that. They are dynamic by nature. If you want database constraints, you have to specify it in your migrations. For instance, a :uniq => true would make sure that a value is unique in your model.

Comment: Thanks for replay, but how can I constrain a attribute regrading with a scope? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_uniqueness_of

Comment: a scope is already a way to constrain attributes. Like a scope that gets registered users will always bring you back the registered users.